# Highlight Duplicate Entries with different number of Records

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table which looks like this

[image: Table with names and records]

Is it possible to have a macro to which highlights names "A" and "B" as they have a different number of records at the different places of the sheet? In the above example, "A" has 3 records and down the lane, it has only 2 records?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. What have you tried? Why hasn't it worked? Where is your [mcve], as you would have seen in [ask]?

Comment: Filter by name (eg filter by `A`) then count the rows in each `Range.Area` of the filered range.